How can i make variable in Grafana with probe_success metrics using prometheus-blackbox-exporter
i need to make a burger list, where my analyses will choose value of probe_success. For example they will choose up (or down) and they will see only graphs where probe_success value is what they have choose, how i can do that using PromQL and variables
i tried this promQL query to see graphs where probe_success values was down (turned off) but that didnt work
Query:    probe_success{probe_success="0"}

matches[]=up{job=~"$job",instance=~"$target",probe_success="1"} OR matches[]=down{job=~"$job",instance=~"$target",probe_success="0"}
Actually, i am trying to do smth like that

Nothing like what you are trying exists. Proper syntax to get values of some metric of the instance based on value of the probe_success for same metric would be some_metric and on(instance) probe_success == $variable, with $variable taking values 0 and 1.

Does this answer your question? Prometheus: filter query based on another metric
